# I get bad auth error even though my password is correct

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, web-applications, atlas

So down below is the snippet I use to connect to my database 'journal'. I placed the password within the string itself. The issue is, that whenever use the URL from the `process.env` I get the `Bad auth err`. But if I use the original plain string, it works perfectly. I can perform read, del, write and update operations easily, but if I use the URL from the `.env` file the connection fails.

```js
require('dotenv').config()

const Port = process.env.port
const url = process.env.DB_conn
//'mongodb+srv://gotham:password@journal.4ok3oge.mongodb.net/journal?retryWrites=true&w=majority'

mongoose.set('strictQuery', false)

try {
    mongoose.connect(url,{
        useNewUrlParser : true
    })
}
catch(err) {
    console.log("connectoin failed")
}
```

And down below is my `.env` file:

```js
DB_conn = 'mongodb+srv://gotham:password@journal.4ok3oge.mongodb.net/journal?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
port = 5000
```

Why does this happen with just the env vars, is anything wrong with the way I access the vars in the `.env` file?

I have seen different approaches like using options but those were for connecting to a locally hosted database, so I did not go with that approach. Please help me out!

Comment: If those are your actual login details, you should consider your database compromised.

Comment: Yes, but the data base is not for commercial use and this is from my other account. The actual account details are different from the above i mentioned. By the way, can u spot what's wrong with my code? Thanks for ur time!

Comment: Maybe this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470

Comment: It is a bit different from my problem. My code works but not in the case when i use the url from the .env file. Thanks for the time.

Comment: Are you sure your login details are correct? I've tried, because you said that there are no important data, with pass in original question (that before your edits)